# Help with rails and tinyMce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have been using tinyMce_hammer plugin to use tinymce in my rails app... but right now I also want a way for my users to upload photos and insert them into their wysiwyg editor.... is there a simple way to get this done??.. is there any other wysiwyg editor that works with rails and comes with this feature built in??... what do you reccomend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two plugins claim to offer it - Rails 2.3 - https://github.com/andreferraro/rails_tiny_mce

Rails 3 - https://github.com/sandipransing/rails_tiny_mce

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this in any of the common rich text editors.  I usually have a separate section where users can upload photos and then choose from a variety of layout options.

Comment: well, I was trying to do it the same way wordpress does it.... Didnt think it was that hard... also considering php developers have it already integrated with tinymce with a image upload plugin they advertise on the official tinymce website.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has a couple of commercial image and file management plugins, but they are based on PHP and .Net. However, I haven't seen a Rails version. It's not particularly hard to build your own image manager using a plugin like paperclip and hook into TinyMCE.